# Parsing interface details from .pcap file in python

Tags: python, pcap, dpkt

I have a .pcap file and I am trying to extract the interface and its admin status from this output. Which python module should I use? I have tried pypcapfile and had no luck figuring it out. I also tried dpkt but I am not able to use the correct handler to extract interface details.

My dpkt reader o/p is:

[image]

Comment: Why would you expect to find interface status in a .pcap file? It's a packet capture, it just shows the data that sent or received.

Comment: Well actually, it an SNMPv2c Trap message. The trap message is for interface status change. I need to get that trap message.

Comment: So you want the message `Interface FastEthernet1/0, changed state to up`?

Comment: Yes exactly! But I don't know how to extract that message in dpkt or any pcap python parsing module.